# Missing reference to system calls

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I was looking at this short introduction to assembly on Linux:

http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html#Compiling

I tried to compile the hello world program therein:

```
.data
hw:
    .string "hello world\n"
.text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl    $SYS_write,%eax
    movl    $1,%ebx
    movl    $hw,%ecx
    movl    $12,%edx
    int $0x80
    movl    $SYS_exit,%eax
    xorl    %ebx,%ebx
    int $0x80
```

```
$ gcc -c hello.s
$ ld -s -o hello hello.o
ld: hello.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `SYS_write'
ld: (.text+0x17): undefined reference to `SYS_exit'
```

So, I suppose that I need to tell the linker about where to find those symbols.  (I also know that I can lookup the constants somewhere in /usr/include and then include them as literals).

I suppose with the right invocation, this program would compile, what am I missing?  Or is it just the case that this author is writing in a "meta language" where these $SYS_* items have to be replaced with a kernel specific constant, and I'm just too noob to assembly to recognize that?

Comment: You missed the `.include "defines.h"` which presumably contains the symbols (although I don't see it on that page). But yeah, those are just constants for the system call numbers. See the "syscalls" section further up.

Comment: You probably want to name it `hello.S` (capital S) so gcc will run it through the C preprocessor, and `#include <asm/unistd.h>`, so you can use `__NR_write`.  Of course you need to use `gcc -m32` to make 32-bit code and get the right header for 32-bit call numbers.

Comment: Thanks, if either of you guys wants to make a proper "answer" to this question, I can accept it.  My issue is solved.

Comment: I do not have `"defines.h"` header. On this system, those constants are in `syscall.h`, however adding `.include "syscall.h"`  and `-I/usr/include` (strange I have to do this) compiles the code fine (as without the .include anyway), but does not link, producing the same error as shown in the question. Something has changed since 2018? :(
1. `gcc -c prog.S -o prog.o -m32 -I/usr/include`  2. `gcc -o prog prog.o -m32` => `(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to SYS_write'` and `(.text+0x50): undefined reference to 'SYS_exit'`